# What can cause IE9 to fail on a redirect?

Tags: asp.net

I'm loooking at an existing web forms app that I didn't write. It's working as expected in IE8 and FF, but fails in IE9 with:

> "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

The code is a simple handler that's doing a context.Response.Redirect.

Using Fiddler, I can see the 302 response, so everything looks fine.

Any ideas why IE9 behaves differently, or what I can do to fix?

Edit due to request for code:

Sure, here's the line:
context.Response.Redirect("file:" & Filename.Replace("/", "\"))

Fiddler shows:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 09 Aug 2012 19:01:24 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Location: file:J:\Replay\Meetings\Meetings-2012.pdf
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 254

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="file:J:\Replay\Meetings\Meetings-2012.pdf">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can we see the code as well as the output from Fiddler? They may provide relevant information.

Comment: If you visit the destination url directly, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm asking just to make sure, but do you have *J:\Replay\Meetings\Meetings-2012.pdf* file locally on your disk? The *file://* protocol is used only to access local files. I suppose it's ok, as you wrote it works as expected in other browsers.

If so, I've read that this kind of error can be caused by invalid url to the file.
Try to redirect like this:

```
context.Response.Redirect("file://" & Filename);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the author did not use file://, but it does work in other browsers. I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why is this code using *file://* protocol at all. Is this a network share? **Do a simple test:** change it to an URL of some file (or image) available on the network, starting with http:// protocol. If this works correctly on all browsers, inluding IE9, create a virtual directory on IIS and use it instead of physical path to the file on disk. If it works for you and you need more information about this, let me know.

Comment: Yes, this is a network share. I asked around and it was designed this way because these could be large files (videos etc.) and each location has their own J drive. So someone won't be pulling lots of data from hundreds of miles away.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to a file with *http://* protocol for tests? If this worked, it's clearly something with file:// handling. If all the loations used separate IIS, they could be configured to use virtual directory path instead of a physical path.

Comment: thanks for the info. Using http:// had no effect. However, if I use file:// with the UNC path instead of the J drive, it does work. I still need to figure out a way to go to different servers, though. So maybe it's something with IE9 and mapped drive names.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a zone elevation issue.  Specifically, IE tries to prevent sites in one security zone from elevating themselves to another security zone.  Redirecting to your local machine from outside your local machine is considered dangerous.

Possible fixes (I am not sure if these will work in IE9):
1.  Add the site that triggers these redirections to the Trusted zone.
2.  Change your security settings.  Notice the "Websites in less privileged web content zone can navigate into this zone" setting (Internet Options -> Internet Zone -> Custom Level).  You need to set that to "Enable" or "Prompt" for the "My Computer Zone." I suspect this can be done by either adding the "My Computer Zone" to your zones list ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315933 ) or by editing the "My Computer Zone" directly (via the registry).  You may also need to add the HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet
Explorer\Main\Disable_Local_Machine_Navigate key (set to 0 REG_DWORD).